# escape filenames in GNU Make

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

My file names have parentesis, tildes, etc. Example: `'Per a què serveixen les equacions de segon grau?.md'`.

I have a simple Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile 
%.md.html: %.md
    echo $<
    ls $<
```

When I run make with this makefile I get this error:

```
$ make Per\ a\ què\ serveixen\ les\ equacions\ de\ segon\ grau\?.md.html
echo Per a què serveixen les equacions de segon grau?.md
Per a què serveixen les equacions de segon grau?.md
ls Per a què serveixen les equacions de segon grau?.md
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'Per': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'a': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'què': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'serveixen': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'les': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'equacions': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'de': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'segon': El fitxer o directori no existeix
ls: no s’ha pogut accedir a 'grau?.md': El fitxer o directori no existeix
make: *** [Makefile:3: Per a què serveixen les equacions de segon grau?.md.html] Error 2
```

because the filename itself is not escaped. Is there anyway to say something like:   `ls escape($<)` in my makefile? Perhaps calling a bash command?

Comment: You need to quote.  `ls "$<"`.  `echo "$<"`.  There are probably other issues, but start there.

Comment: Short answer: it is not possible to use filenames containing whitespace with makefiles.  If you must use filenames containing spaces you'll have to find a different tool to manage your files.

Comment: Let me just say: if all you want to do is pass filenames in on the command line like this, then it can work (as @WilliamPursell says, just quote it for the shell).  But if you want to put the filenames into the makefile in variables, or using `wildcard` or anything like that, it can't (reasonably) be done.  If you search throughout the web you'll find various attempts at hacky workarounds for some specific situations, but there are no complete solutions.

Comment: I would disagree slightly with MadScientist.  There is a "complete solution", but it is a policy solution and not a technical one.  Don't use names that do not match `[a-zA-Z_-.]+`

Comment: :).  I think you forgot `[0-9]` in your list of acceptable characters (and I know what you meant but you have to put `-` at the beginning or end of the class; it can't come in the middle) :).  From a purely make standpoint the only characters it's helpful to avoid are whitespace, `$`, `:`, and `#`.  And of those the only one that is really untenable is whitespace: the rest are annoying but can easily be managed.

Comment: So, there is no solution for manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example, quoting the automatic variable's will work:

```
echo "$<"
ls "$<"
```

However this trick doesn't work for optionally empty variables, or variables containing multiple files. Because of how GNU Make uses whitespace as delimiter in lists it's overall unsuited for dealing with filenames with whitespace in them.